# Why is MinGW gfortran on Windows extremely slow?

Tags: windows, performance, mingw, gfortran

I have installed `gfortran` on my Windows 10 on top of MinGW (I don't remember how, it was some ready package). I wrote this fortran program on file `helloworld.f90`

```
program helloworld

    print *,'Hello World'

end program helloworld
```

and compile it in a Command Prompt with

`gfortran helloworld.f90 -o hello`

I'm testing how long it takes with ptime

```
C:\fortran tests>ptime hello
===  hello ===
 Hello World
Execution time: 23.703 s 

C:\fortran tests>ptime hello
===  hello ===
 Hello World
Execution time: 1.225 s

C:\fortran tests>ptime hello
===  hello ===
 Hello World
Execution time: 1.227 s
```

I tested it without `ptime`, using stop watch by hand, and got similar times so I don't think the `ptime` is causing this. What might cause this extremely slow 1st run 23s? And why is it faster next times? And I think over 1s for this is still weirdly slow. What settings should I look for and how? I could not find anything similar in SOF. Also, on my VirtualBox Ubuntu this problem does not occur, only on the Windows.

Comment: How about a virus scanner and about caching of executable / dll's / paths etc. by Windows? Did you try the same with a small C program?

Comment: My virusscanner is messing up things (see below) and with C it was even worse than with Fortran: the virusscanner removed my  .exe file automatically and warned about suspicious/harmful file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my virusscanner program. Thanks @albert for the tip.

This is a company laptop and I cannot turn off the virusscanner. I booted in the Safe Mode, now the virusscanner is off, and `hello.exe` runs in 0.029s. Seems legit.

Side note: almost any other fortran test program I tried to run in the Safe Mode, failed with an error message "could not find `lib(...).dll`" But that would be another topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you got `gfortran` from somewhere, but you don't know where except that it probably came with MinGW then you probably have a very old version.

You can check the version with `gfortran --version`. It's part of the GCC compiler suite, and at the time of this writing the current version is 11.2.0.

You can get a recent version of the GCC compiler suite as a standalone build (no installer, just unzip) from https://winlibs.com/ which contains a working `gfortran`.

Comment: Are old versions of gfortran particularly poor at print statements?

Comment: No necessarely, but this may happen when mixing different standard libraries, and as you're not sure where you got `gfortran` from it's best to make sure you have a solid working environment... Anyway, the standalone build doesn't require installation so you can try it without uninstalling or touching your existing installation.

Comment: Yes my MinGW was version 6.3, got new one now it is version 11.2. But the problem remains; in fact it slowed down even more to 32s for the first run after compilation

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce your problem. Have you tried to run it on another pc? Also you can try to build without debug information and/or static build.

Comment: Have you tried without virusscanner?

Comment: It's a company laptop so I cannot turn off the virusscanner. But I did boot in Safe Mode -> virusscanner was off. And, the hello.exe runs now in 0.029 seconds. Seems normal now.